# domain user is shown as DOM\USER in login screen

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, windows-domain, sysadmin

while i try to login to my pc I have my username automatically shown like <DOM\USER>
it used to be only (USERNAME) idk what happened and I searched for this problem but i can't seem to find anything

[image: example]

Comment: (1) Is "DOM" the name of your computer? (2) Have you added more users to your computer or joined some new domain or workgroup? (3) Have you recently updated Windows with a major upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be that i removed my display name un accident

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what has changed on your computer, but
you may set your computer to be the default domain this way:

- Run `gpedit.msc`
- Position to
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Settings > System > Logon*
- Double-click "Assign a default domain for logon"
- Select *Enabled*
- Under Options, provide the name of your computer
- Click OK
- Reboot.

You should now be able to specify the user name without a domain.
If Windows insists on displaying the user-name with a domain, this is not
harmful.